# UIStackView stretching out sub view aligning it

Tags: swift, uistackview

I'm trying to lay out a StackView programatically, the effect I would like to achieve is
**[image: strong text]**

but instead I am getting

[image]

I do not understand why the loadingDotView is stretching to fill up all the space?

```
   let loadingDotView: UIView = {
        let ldv = UIView()
        ldv.backgroundColor = .white
        ldv.alpha = 0
        ldv.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)
        ldv.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        ldv.layer.masksToBounds = true
        ldv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return ldv
    }()

    let dotsStackView: UIStackView = {
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = .horizontal
        stackView.distribution = .equalSpacing
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return stackView
    }()
```

Setup code...

```
   view.addSubview(dotsStackView)

    
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            dotsStackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20),
            dotsStackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
            dotsStackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            dotsStackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
        ])
    
    

    dotsStackView.addArrangedSubview(loadingDotView)
    dotsStackView.addArrangedSubview(loadingDotView)
    dotsStackView.addArrangedSubview(loadingDotView)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ( closure )

```
let loadingDotView: UIView = {
    let ldv = UIView()
    ldv.backgroundColor = .white
    ldv.alpha = 0
    ldv.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)
    ldv.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    ldv.layer.masksToBounds = true
    ldv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return ldv
}()
```

returns same object every access so only one appears , make it ( computed property ) to create a new one every access

```
var loadingDotView: UIView {
    let ldv = UIView()
    ldv.backgroundColor = .white
    ldv.alpha = 0
    ldv.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)
    ldv.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    ldv.layer.masksToBounds = true
    ldv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return ldv
}
```

And add

```
stackView.spacing = 20
stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much :)